# You must provide <repository> <refspec> When trying to publish on gh-pages?

Tags: reactjs, git, github, github-pages, git-subtree

I want to publish my react-app to `gh-pages` but because my `index.html` file is located inside of `react-app/public/index.html` I can't publish to github pages because github searches for the `index.html` inside of the main repository.

So I tried following [This tutorial on how to do it using a subtree](https://gist.github.com/cobyism/4730490)

But, when I type in `git subtree push --prefix dist origin gh-pages`
It returns `You must provide <repository> <refspec>`

NOTE: I did change "dist" to "public" which is the name of my folder.

I am not very skilled it git and github and I am wondering what my mistake is here? And how do I publish to gh-pages when my `index.html` is located in a folder inside of the repository?

Comment: `git subtree push --prefix dist origin gh-pages` is correct: it should not be complaining here. Do you have a [mre] someone can try out?

Comment: [You seem to have fixed your own problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73491577/1256452). Is this question still useful?

Answer (score 0):

you can solve your problem by simply going to .gitignore and deleting the dist name from the line where it is, the error happens because git cannot read the dist