# Published site from dist folder is completely blank? [REACT]

Tags: reactjs, github, github-pages

I create a react-app using `npx create-react-app` and published the app to GitHub using vscode. My repository contains a public folder inside of the main repository that has my `index.html` file.

[Here is my repository on GitHub](https://github.com/AtanasovCode/product-preview-card)

I then run the following command in my vscode terminal:

`git subtree push --prefix public origin gh-pages`

According to [this tutorial on how to publish to github with a dist folder](https://gist.github.com/cobyism/4730490) I did everything correctly.

When I check my repository it has 2 branches, `main` and `gh-pages` however if I go to my deployed site I get a completely blank site. What am I missing here?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The page isn't completely blank, if you visit https://atanasovcode.github.io/product-preview-card/ and view the source, you see the contents of your `index.html` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
    <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is installed on a
      user's mobile device or desktop. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/
    -->
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <!--
      Notice the use of %PUBLIC_URL% in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@500;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Fraunces:opsz,wght@9..144,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 
    <title>Product Preview Cardp</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```

There are some comments in there that seem relevant:

> This HTML file is a template.
>
> If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.
>
> You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
> The build step will place the bundled scripts into the  tag.
>
> To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
> To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.

Comment: I used the command ````npm run build```` which made my app into production mode. Now in my ````index.html```` file it says "You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.". How do I go about doing this?